# "blockade" a include which is added through if condition in a specific page

Tags: php, include

I have an if condition that adds a header using the include in my pages if the user is logged in and another header if he is not logged in.

It works fine, but I ran into a problem...

On the login page for example, I wouldn't like the header to appear, but the if adds to all my pages.

Is there any way I can "block" pages that I don't want the header/include added?

(I don't speak English fluently, sorry if there are any grammar mistakes)

code:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('user_login')) {
    include 'logged_in_header.php';
}else {
    include 'logged_out_header.php';
}
```

I already tried to remove using javascript, but it would be better if not even add

Comment: Possibly keep an array of `views` (pages) that must not show a header and check against the array of views (use e.g. [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @berend! Sorry I'm a bit of a layman in php, how could I integrate this into the code above? I read the documentation but did not understand. For example I don't want it to be included in the login.php page, how can I do that?

Comment: something along [these](https://3v4l.org/9B9OO) lines. In the snippet I commented out your includes for testing.